# how to make simple PHP visitor counter for my website

Tags: php, html, png

First this should be really easy for any person with php knowledge. I am trying to count the visited uses and display the number as an image, the images are name "0.png" - "9.png" it chooses it based on the count and it is supposed to add it to the canvas.png which is a 296x76 image serving as a background for the png's where are sized 56x76. the counter works but the images do not show

list of errors here followed by weird text

```
libpng warning: iCCP: profile 'icc': 'RGB ': RGB color space not permitted on grayscale PNG
libpng warning: iCCP: profile 'icc': 'RGB ': RGB color space not permitted on grayscale PNG
libpng warning: iCCP: profile 'icc': 'RGB ': RGB color space not permitted on grayscale PNG
libpng warning: iCCP: profile 'icc': 'RGB ': RGB color space not permitted on grayscale PNG
libpng warning: iCCP: profile 'icc': 'RGB ': RGB color space not permitted on grayscale PNG
```

//html

```
<div>
<p> <center> Number of visitors:</center> </p>
<center><img alt="Visitor counter" src="counter.php" /></center>
</div>
```

//counter.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$counter_name = "counter.txt";

// Check if a text file exists.
//If not create one and initialize it to zero.
if (!file_exists($counter_name)) {
    $f = fopen($counter_name, "w");
    fwrite($f,"0");
    fclose($f);
}
// Read the current value of our counter file
$f = fopen($counter_name,"r");
$counterVal = fread($f, filesize($counter_name));
fclose($f);

// Has visitor been counted in this session?
// If not, increase counter value by one
if(!isset($_SESSION['hasVisited'])){
    $_SESSION['hasVisited']="yes";
    $counterVal++;
    $f = fopen($counter_name, "w");
    fwrite($f, $counterVal);
    fclose($f);
}

$counterVal = str_pad($counterVal, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
$chars = preg_split('//', $counterVal);
$im = imagecreatefrompng("canvas.png");

$src1 = imagecreatefrompng ("digits/$chars[1].png");
$src2 = imagecreatefrompng ("digits/$chars[2].png");
$src3 = imagecreatefrompng ("digits/$chars[3].png");
$src4 = imagecreatefrompng ("digits/$chars[4].png");
$src5 = imagecreatefrompng ("digits/$chars[5].png");

imagecopymerge($im, $src1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 56, 76, 100);
imagecopymerge($im, $src2, 60, 0, 0, 0, 56, 76, 100);
imagecopymerge($im, $src3, 120, 0, 0, 0, 56, 76, 100);
imagecopymerge($im, $src4, 180, 0, 0, 0, 56, 76, 100);
imagecopymerge($im, $src5, 240, 0, 0, 0, 56, 76, 100);

// Output and free from memory
header('Content-Type: image/png');
echo imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

It is supposed to give an image of the count and show it on my index.html but all I see is a "?" where the image is supposed to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some serious efficiency issues here but let's start with the basics.

First and foremost, this line:
echo imagepng($im);

Take out the echo. If you don't pass a filename to imagepng(), then the function will output image data. However your echo is displaying the RETURN value of that function which is a boolean. So the echo will actually add data that corrupts the rest of the image data.

Next, your grayscale warnings are due to canvas.png being a grayscale image. You need to open it up and re-save it as a truecolor image so that when you copy in your other images, their colors exist within the canvas.png palette.

Third, using a text file for your counter data is a bad idea. At any point, if you have two simultaneous visitors, you will end up with incorrect data. A database will prevent this.

Fourth, using separate image files for each digit is inefficient. I presume you're using stylized digits so you can't just write text (unless you have the original font). With that assumption, you should have all the digits side-by-side in one image and then copy the digits as necessary.

Alternatively, if you want to use separate digit images, use PHP to simply generate the HTML for individual img tags side-by-side. It would be far more efficient than generating a new image on the fly with GD.

Fifth, you have a $counterVal which is a string. You can access the individual characters in $counterVal like you would in an array:

$counterVal[0] is the first character/digit, etc... You don't need preg_split() at all.

Finally, I always recommend that people not use visit counters at all. There's no benefit. It is never accurate, and if the number is low, then you're only showing the rest of the world that the page is not popular. If the number is high, then other visitors don't really care anyway, and you have just spent a lot of your web server resources on thousands or millions of additional PHP executions to generate this data.

If you're curious about traffic to the page, your most accurate mechanism is to analyze your web server logs. It'll tell you the number of hits per page and a LOT more.

Answer (score 1):

`echo imagepng` is not needed since the **imagepng** function by default sends output to the browser. See documentation for [imagepng](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php).

As I understand you need **$counterVal** to hold 5 digits. The **str_pad** function will not produce a string with fixed number of characters. It simply adds a given number of characters to the left or right of the input string. See documentation for [str_pad](https://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php). To ensure that **$counterVal** has 5 digits, following code may be used:

```
$len          = strlen($counterVal);
$zero_count   = (5 - $len);
$zero_padding = str_repeat("0", $zero_count);
$counterVal   = $zero_padding . $counterVal;
```

The error message you posted suggests that the **canvas.png** image is a gray scale image, but the digit images are in RGB format.

In grayscale images, each pixel has a value between 0 and 255. In RGB images each pixel has a three tuple value given by (r, g, b), where r, g and b each have values between 0 and 255.

You can try to use the [imagecopymergegray](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymergegray.php), which converts the RGB pixels to gray scale before copying from source to destination. If this does not work, then you can use an image editor to convert the canvas image and digit images to same format. For example both may be converted to grayscale or RGB.

As mentioned in the answer from @jhilgeman, its not efficient to generate a new visitor counter image using GD for each visit. It would be much better to simply output image tags for the digits.

Answer (score 1):

Make it easy i hope this answer helps you , echo the txt file that have the number of viewers and add a background image to it

```html
<div>
        <p> <center> Number of visitors:</center> </p>
        <center>  <div style="    position: relative;
        width: 24px;
       
        background-image: url(https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/elegant-white-background-with-shiny-lines_1017-17580.jpg);
        padding: 50px"><?php echo file_get_contents("counter.txt"); ?></div>
        </center>
        </div>
```